# how to handle foreign key with morph one to many files

Tags: php, laravel

I have these tables:

```
file:
id - path - meme_type


fileable:
id - file_id - fileable_id - fileable_type


ticket_bodies:
id - title
```

each row of `TickeBody` have multi files. now how to implement morph functions? (I don't want to combine `file` table with fileable table)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

`App\Models\File`:

```
public function fileable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

`App\Models\TicketBody`:

```
public function files(){
    return $this->morphMany(App\Models\File::class, 'fileable');
}
```